# Webpack different versions problem with starting project

Tags: webpack

I've encountered a problem where my `npm ls webpack` outputs two versions (4.42.1 and 4.42.0) of webpack and I can't seem to start it.

```
├─┬ @storybook/addon-storyshots@5.3.18
│ └─┬ @storybook/core@5.3.18
│   ├─┬ corejs-upgrade-webpack-plugin@2.2.0
│   │ └── webpack@4.42.1  deduped
│   └── webpack@4.42.1  deduped
├─┬ @storybook/react@5.3.18
│ └── webpack@4.42.1 
└─┬ react-scripts@3.4.1
  └── webpack@4.42.0
```

I've been crawling around and removing node_modules and locks didn't solve the issue so I am reaching out to make use of some more experienced developers.

Of course it all starts with :

```
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "webpack": "4.42.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and this is what I had to do to get going.

1. Create a file with the name `.env` in your client root.
2. Add the line `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` to that file.
3. Restart the web
       serving process (in my case it was VS 2019/IIS Express and a
       recompile was enough)

Hope this helps someone.